# How to clear "Move To" and "Copy To" Explorer Tool Bar on WIndows 10

Tags: windows-10

I'm searching how to clear the options available in "Move To" and "Copy To" dropdown menu on Windows 10.

In the image bellow you can see that Copy To have as lot of options. How can I clear it?

[image: Copy to with a lot of options]

Comment: Just checked here. The entries are coming from Explorer Jumplist. Open Folder Options, and uncheck "show frequently used" and click OK. Re-check it back. But the Pinned items remain.

Comment: Your tip gave me the solution. Actually, I have clicked on the button "Clean" bellow of option you described above.

Comment: Yes. that'll do.. and the easiest option i missed.. To prevent the frequent folders from being populated, simply keep the option unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries are coming from Explorer Jumplists (and the same is shown in the Quick access section.)

Open Folder Options, and click `Clear`. To prevent recent folders from being populated again, uncheck `Show frequently used folders in Quick access` and click OK. The Pinned items will remain.